# where should i save my drivers and advertisement files

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005

i'm creating a shopping website for buying computer parts. i want to accept advertisement(images) and also provide a way to upload drivers(exe or msi) of the items locally. i already have the following tables in the SQL Server 2005 database:

```
--here is the driver table
tblDriver (driver_id bigint primary key identity(1,1), 
   driver_name nvarchar(max) not null, driver_address nvarchar(500) not null)
--here is the ad table
tblAd (ad_id bigint primary key identity(1,1), ad_address nvarchar(500) not null)
```

so where should i save the actual files? i'm looking for a clean solution with no truble for CRUD operations.

Answer (score 1):

As usual - you may either store the files into DB, or store them into filesystem.

Storing in the DB has its advantages - you always will have a consistent backup.

Store in filesystem for faster file read.

**But** you may combine both methods and store files in DB as [FILESTREAM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) column. Although if I remember right - FILESTREAMs are available only starting from Sql Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

IMO better solution is to save the files in file system and store the path or location in database.